# JDBC Oracle 12 allow jdbc outgoing traffic in firewalld

Tags: redhat, centos7, oracle, firewalld, jdbc

I'm installing an application which needs an Oracle DB on my server.
The DB is hosted on another dedicated server.

The application is using JDBC to connect to the DB.

I have tested the connection with sqlplus and the result is ok with and without tnsnames.ora :

```
export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/network/admin
export ORACLE_SID=MYDB    
sqlplus user@MYDB
```

is ok.

Without tnsnames.ora I can also connect to the DB:

```
sqlplus user/pwd@server:1521/MYDB
```

is working fine.

But when I connect through jdbc java driver, the connection is with the following exception:

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:456)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:397)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:437)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:954)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:639)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:29)
```

By deactivating the firewalld service, the connection is OK with JDBC.

In the firewalld, I have created the following "oracle" service (in /etc/firewalld/services):

```
[root@frtls3dxr2017-i 1]# ll /etc/firewalld/services/oracle.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root root 196 Jun 15 10:00 /etc/firewalld/services/oracle.xml
[root@frtls3dxr2017-i 1]# ll /etc/firewalld/services/oracle.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root root 196 Jun 15 10:00 /etc/firewalld/services/oracle.xml
[root@frtls3dxr2017-i 1]# firewall-cmd --list-services
tomee_fcsremote http 3dnotification tomee_3dcomment tomee_fedsearch dhcpv6-client tomee_3dspaceinternal tomee_3ddashboard tomee_3dpassport tomee_3dspace ssh https oracle tomee_fcscentral
[root@frtls3dxr2017-i 1]# cat /etc/firewalld/services/oracle.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>oracle port for jdbc</short>
  <description>oracle
    Firewall rules</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="1521"/>
</service>
```

Do I need to add more port in the service xml file to allow connection to the DB (outgoing traffic)?

Answer (score 0):

It was not a firewall issue.

The problem was with the rngd service not using /dev/urandom.
I had to modify the service unit file to add -r /dev/urandom:

> ExecStart=/sbin/rngd -f -r /dev/urandom

It could also be solved by changing the java.security securerandom.source key:

> securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom